# Does Konashenkov typically take questions after his briefings for the media?

Tags: russian-federation, military

Western sources typically show brief clips of Russia MoD spokesman Lt. General Igor Konashenkov giving his media briefings about the war, but the clips shown in the West are too short to get an idea how these briefings are organized.

Does he just say what he has to say, or is that that followed by questions from (Russian) journalists attending these briefings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no questions from any journalists, Konashenkov is just reading the official MoD statements in a very monotone way. His statements always begin with: "The Russian armed forces continue a special military operation". Then he explains what successes have been achieved, or if you like it better claimed to be achieved. That's the whole briefing. This briefings can be seen on the official Russian MoD channel.

Comment: Yeah, in the meantime, I managed to find some longer footage posted on YouTube, back from the Syria briefings. It seems that [press, I assume] correspondents were present in the room for those, but there was no questions section/time.
https://youtu.be/PfATgjvHVHg?t=800